# jQuery .fadeOut not triggering on absolute positioned element

Tags: jquery, hide, fadein, fadeout

Strange problem happening where the end of these 2 blocks of code (this part: **$('#next-back').delay(500).fadeOut(300);**) doesn't trigger (and it used to!)

```
$('.menu-contact').click(function() {
        $('#about').fadeOut(300);$('.menu-about').removeClass('selected');
        $('#contact').delay(500).fadeIn(600);
        $(this).addClass('selected');$('#next-back').delay(500).fadeOut(300);
    });

    $('.menu-about').click(function() {
        $('#contact').fadeOut(300);$('.menu-contact').removeClass('selected');
        $('#about').delay(500).fadeIn(600);
        $(this).addClass("selected");$('#next-back').delay(500).fadeOut(300);
    });
```

I'm at a loss here. This is really simple stuff and it doesn't work and I'm embarrassed to even have to post it here. If I change the code to `$('#next-back').hide();` the element will hide.

Here's the working example: http://fixxed.com/test/bp/visual-effects-color-grading-design.html

When you click on CONTACT or ABOUT the "NEXT" at the bottom right should fadeOut as the overlay fades in.  And when you click the litte "close" inside the overlay it will fadeIn the "NEXT"
Oddly, the "NEXT" will flash when you click the "close"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to not use absolute positioning on your .next div (in #next-back), when i remove it and try `$('#next-back').fadeOut()` it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from both about and contact.

```
$('#next-back').delay(500).fadeOut(300);
```

I feel it won't make any difference, if you remove.